# Handling delay in entry of OTP for log in validation

Tags: security, authentication, validation, passwords, login

There's an application, which accepts a user id and password to login. Validation of the id and password is processed by another system. Now after password validation, the application generates a One Time Passcode (OTP) and sends it as an SMS or email to the user.

This OTP expires in 15-30 minutes. Only when the OTP is validated successfully does the user's login complete.

If the user has two devices, and he enters his password in one device, an OTP is generated. But he doesn't use the OTP on the first device. He uses his second device to log in again, and enters his password there. Since it is within 15-30 minutes, the same OTP is generated again. Now he can log in to two devices with the same OTP.

Does this scenario appear to be good?

Continuing the scenario, his id is locked meanwhile for some reason. He attempts to enter the OTP in either of the devices. Now should we allow the login? Otherwise, should we check the id status every time an OTP is validated?

Similarly, in the 15-30 minute interval, if password is changed via the help desk, should we reset the existing sessions that have successful password validation but are waiting for the OTP? Or can we allow the login with the older password itself?

The technical problem here is that password validation is in one system, but the OTP validation is in another system, and they are mutually exclusive. They don't communicate with each other.

Is this OTP validation procedure appropriate?

Comment: Sounds like you need a device id or an application instance id.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, we can introduce a device id. But, I am concerned, if I really to consider these negative scenarios?

Comment: Negative scenarios?

Comment: Like id locked/password changed  before the OTP expiry. Should we still allow OTP validation ?

Comment: I understand password changed, and I think you want that to happen before the OTP expiry.  What do you mean by "id is locked?"

Comment: Like, after OTP is generated for an userID.. His userId is locked. and should we again validate the user's status when he enter the OTP?

Comment: You didn't explain what you meant by "id is locked."

Comment: ROb, sorry for not being clear. My scenario is like this. I enter the passord and id , and my application successfully validated it and generated an OTP. I have 15 mins to input my OTP. Now, my id (user Id) has been locked for further login in System 1(Not through application but behind the screens). But now I have a session, where id is already validated and waiting for OTP validation in System 2. Should I honour the OTP or go back to System 1 for id's active status?

Comment: Many people validate OTP's using a different device.  I know I do.

Comment: I am afraid, you didnt get my problem. Should I validate the User id's status or look for any password change history before validating the OTP ? Though in previous screen, I validated both user id and his password. Just because OTP validation has a 30 minutes interval.

Comment: I think you should validate the OTP one time (within the 30 minute window), and reject any subsequent attempts at validating that OTP and any attempts made after 30 minutes..

Comment: Yes, oncee an OTP is validated, it is invalidated. The password can be changed or the UserID can be locked via helpdesk call. This should hard stop control the OTP validation. In my worst case, password is changed behind the screens via help desk and the application now has already validated session waiting for OTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this OTP validation procedure appropriate?

Your validation procedure seems mostly okay, but your *generation* procedure certainly is not.

> Since it is within 15-30 minutes, the same OTP is generated again. Does this scenario appear to be good?

**Two logins should never produce the same passcode. Ever.**

When a login is attempted, *generate a brand new passcode*. Expire the old one immediately.

Going back to validation, though, you really should not accept the same OTP twice.

All your other questions, as far as I can tell, become moot when taking the above into consideration.

Comment: Thanks, just to confirm we need not confirm the password status for this user, after OTP? Because password can be changed with a call to help desk.

Comment: Also, the newer OTP should be allowed in the older session? The OTP is just sticky to the user id or to the session as well ?

Answer (score 1):

When calculating OTP values you should rely on open standards like HOTP or TOTP in RFC4226 and RFC6238. In your case - if you want the OTP value to be usable for 15 minutes - you need to use the event base HOTP (RFC4226).

This is a typical scenario as handled by [privacyidea](http://privacyidea.org). Entering the correct password triggers the sending of an SMS where you can define the validitiy period of the sent OTP value. privacyidea supports a bunch of token types. One is the [SMS token](http://privacyidea.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/tokenconfig/sms.html#sms-otp-token). You can use the REST API to trigger the SMS.